# Disable UIScrollView scroll when dragging inside subview - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

To implement charts in my app, I'm using this library: https://github.com/AAChartModel/AAChartKit-Swift

My chart view is inside an UIScrollView. When the user is dragging through values in the chart view, I want my UIScrollView to not scroll at the same time.

I tried implementing this by overriding theses methods:

```
open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    guard let touchPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
}

open override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

But even if I override these methods in a AAChartView extension, touches are recognised only around the chart.

Comment: Have you tried implementing [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer?language=swift)?

Comment: I don't know how to implement this...